# Squid3 URLrewrite - Unable to configure

Tags: mysql, rewrite, debian-wheezy, lua

I have Squid3-3.4.8 on Debian Wheezy. It is performing caching duty. I just want to replace one jpg url to another URL in my local server or outside. I have tried solutions like `Volta`, `squidred`, `asqredir`.

For Volta i'm stuck at:

```
root@S:~/Volta/volta-0.3.0# make
Package lua5.2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `lua5.2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'lua5.2' found
cc -O2 -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include    -c -o accept_loop.o accept_loop.c
In file included from accept_loop.c:31:0:
volta.h:77:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [accept_loop.o] Error 1
```

Lua is at:

`/root/Lua/lua-5.3.3`
I was following the procedure in an `INSTALL` file.

What else can use to accomplish my task?

Are there any other applications that I can use to be successful in doing a URL rewrite?

Source: `https://bitbucket.org/mahlon/volta/overview`

Comment: sudo apt-get install liblua5.2-dev

Answer (score 0):

> replace one jpg url to another url in my local server

Wouldn't it be simpler to just write your own:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$| = 1;
while (<>) {
   @line = split;
   $_ = $line[0];
   s/www\.example\.com\/one\.jpg/www.example.com\/other.jpg/g;
   print $_ . "\n";
}
```